Python asyncio stuck sometime
I am new in Python.I want to create n-Tasks that run in parallel. I have code example using asyncio. The code run fine for about 1 minute but sometimes there is a strange time like in the picture. Please let me know where I went wrong and how to fix it. Thanks you
import asyncio
import time
tasks = []
async def task1():
    try:
        while True:
            start_time = time.time()    
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
            print(f"Task 1 running, taking {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Task 1 cancelled!")
        raise

async def task2():
    try:
        while True:
            start_time = time.time()    
            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
            print(f"Task 2 running, taking {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Task 2 cancelled!")
        raise
async def task3():
    try:
        while True:
            start_time = time.time()    
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(f"Task 3 running, taking {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Task 3 cancelled!")
        raise
...... Multi task create here
async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(task1())
    tasks.append(t1)
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(task2())
    tasks.append(t2)
    t3 = asyncio.create_task(task3())
    tasks.append(t3)
..... Multi task add here
    try:
        # Run tasks indefinitely
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Gracefully shutting down...")
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
        t3.cancel()
        t4.cancel()
        t5.cancel()
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

# Run the event loop
asyncio.run(main())

Task hang on red cycle
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 1 running, taking 0.20 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 2 running, taking 0.25 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 3 running, taking 0.30 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 4 running, taking 0.40 seconds
2024-11-25 12:02:53 Task 1 running, taking -11.26 seconds
2024-11-25 12:02:53 Task 2 running, taking -11.21 seconds
2024-11-25 12:02:53 Task 3 running, taking -11.17 seconds
2024-11-25 12:02:53 Task 1 running, taking 0.20 seconds
2024-11-25 12:02:53 Task 5 running, taking -10.97 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 2 running, taking 11.69 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 4 running, taking 0.37 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 1 running, taking 11.64 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:04 Task 3 running, taking 11.74 seconds
2024-11-25 12:03:05 Task 2 running, taking 0.25 seconds


Nothing suspicious in the code. Is your RTC OK?

@KlausD.
I have tried this code on many PC running the Windows OS (Via Docker) and all have the same results as above. I tracked the results from Docker Desktop output

What is especially suspicious is the timestamp from the logging that seems to be independent of your code. Figure out why this goes wrong and you have the root cause.

Using time.time() which can jump if the system clock is adjusted. Use  time.monotonic() instead of time.time() for more accurate duration measurements

@Bhargav The problem is sloved, thanks you
